# How to retrieve screenshots of a package in ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, python

i'm developing an application which manipulates packages in ubuntu. I'm working with python. I need to retrieve screenshots of packages by using package-name. For example, say that package-name is filezilla. By knowing package-name, i want to retrieve filezilla's screenshots and then display these screenshots in my application's gui.

When i know the package-name, i can retrieve all details of a package by using python-apt. But i don't know how to retrieve the package's screenshots.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is true that the graphical installer has screenshots. I wonder too because as far as I know those screenshots are not inside the package. They may have them on their servers only...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The screenshot that are displayed in Software Center are provided by [screenshots.ubuntu.com](http://screenshots.ubuntu.com/)/[screenshots.debian.net](https://screenshots.debian.net/) They can be retrieved like so:

```
http://screenshots.ubuntu.com/thumbnail-with-version/$PACKAGE/$VERSION
http://screenshots.ubuntu.com/screenshot-with-version/$PACKAGE/$VERSION
```

or:

```
http://screenshots.ubuntu.com/thumbnail/$PACKAGE
http://screenshots.ubuntu.com/screenshot/$PACKAGE
```